# How to use an array in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var fruit:Array = new Array();

var frName:String;

var i:Number;

save_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, storeName);

function storeName(Event:MouseEvent)
{

 frName = name_txt.text;

 fruit[i] = frName;

 i++;
}

detail_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dispName);

function dispName(Event:MouseEvent)

{

 for(i=0; i<=1; i++)

 {
  trace(fruit[i]);
 }
}
```

The script has two buttons: one for saving the text in a `fruit` array and the other for displaying the text.

However, when I click the display button, the script shows **undefined** as output in actionscript. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined your "i" variable you never set a value... e.g. it is "undefined".  Just set it to zero.

```
var i:Number = 0;
```

Comment: bt i put the value in for loop also for i=0 why twice I have to give the value??

Comment: When you are populating the array originally... The first index you are storing on is "undefined"... After that, if you're lucky (I haven't tested) the ++ increments from undefined to 1.  By ensuring the values are stored correctly, they'll extract correctly too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

declaring i as a global variable is making things difficult. Perhaps try rewritting like so:

```
var fruit:Array = new Array();

save_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, storeName);

function storeName(Event:MouseEvent){
  fruit.push(name_txt.text);
}

detail_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dispName);

function dispName(Event:MouseEvent){
  for(var f:String in fruit){
    trace(f);
  }
}
```

Comment: i m sorry bt i have jst started AS 3.0 and i don't know the push command etc. as they are advanced technique i think so...

Comment: Adobe's Livedocs are an excellent reference: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

it's often easier to use built-in functionality, rather than try and implement your own looping, adding, etc.